# How to use :nth-of-type selector with the :before selector in css3?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am working in a Drupal 8 project. I have a sidebar where I have an unordered list inserted in the DOM dinamically. I have been trying to insert some SVGs through CSS3 pseudoclass :before and it worked. However, I need to insert a different SVGs for different anchor tags on that list. So I am trying to do it like so:

```
ul {
 li {
  a {
    &:nth-of-type(1):before {
     //Code goes here
    }
    &:nth-of-type(2):before {
     //Code goes here
    }
    &:nth-of-type(3):before {
     //Code goes here
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance

HTML markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>">Menu Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>">Menu Link 2</a>
                                        <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>">Submenu-sidebar 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>">Submenu-sidebar 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>">Submenu-sidebar 3</a>
    </li>
    </ul>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>">Menu Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>">Menu Link 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>">Menu Link 5</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I have tried so far:

```
ul {
     border: none;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
     -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0px 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
      box-shadow: 1px 0px 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: rem(280px);
      li {
          a {
            background-color: $white;
            color: $greyish-brown;
            display: block;
            padding: rem(20px) rem(35px);

            &:hover {
               background-color: $blue-green;
               color: $white;
            }
            }
            a:nth-of-type(1):before {
              @extend %svg-sidebar-decorations;
              background-image: url("../images/picto-info-sant.svg");
            }
             a:nth-of-type(2):before {
                @extend %svg-sidebar-decorations;
                background-image: url("../images/picto-infosocial.svg");

             }
             a:nth-of-type(2):before {
                @extend %svg-sidebar-decorations;
                background-image: url("../images/picto-infosocial.svg");
             }
            }

    %svg-sidebar-decorations {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: rem(14px);
    height: rem(16px);
    margin-top: rem(3);
    margin-right: rem(10px);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Your code would suggest that you have three `a` tags within each `li`. Is this the case? Or is there actually one `a` within each `li`? Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: Hello @Turnip 
I have had edit my previous question to give you a little bit of more context. I have a tag for each li and I am basically trying to insert a different SVG on each a tag with the :before pseudo class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nth-child(n)` instead of `nth-of-type(n)` and move these selectors to the `li` level.

Your SCSS (?) might look something like this:

```
ul {
  li {
    &:nth-child(1) a:before {
      //Code goes here
    }
    &:nth-child(2) a:before {
      //Code goes here
    }
    &:nth-child(3) a:before {
      //Code goes here
    }
  }
}
```

[Example CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yZLwPa)

Comment: It works perfectly now! Man... thank you very much for the help!